# Rust test - how fail verbosely if Result object is not Ok?

Tags: rust, anyhow

My use case is pretty simple - if an actual object is not an Ok variant, I would like this test to fail explicitly by showing what it contains instead:

```rust
fn test_foo() {
  let actual = fn_that_returns_result();

  // not verbose enough in case it is actually an Err:
  // assert!(res.is_ok());
}
```

I can not make an exact comparison here because Ok variant's inner state is dynamic.

The method below kind of works but I'm wondering if it's fine or perhaps there's a more idiomatic solution to this?

```rust
fn test_foo() {
  let actual = fn_that_returns_result();

  match res {
    Ok(_) => {},
    Err(err) => panic!("{}", err) // anyhow::Error
  }
}
```

---

Update: just to be clear, I would like the original error to stay intact and not be overwritten in assert(therefore cant use `.expect` or override it via `assert!`'s 2nd argument)

Comment: Do `unwrap()` or `expect()` not do the job?

Comment: Hint: `fn_that_returns_result().expect("Uh-oh")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rust, tests are considered failed when they [panic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html). In fact, that's about all that macros like `assert!` do under the hood: evaluate a condition, and if it is not met, panic with an error message.

`Result` includes methods like [unwrap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) and [expect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect), both of which panic with the error value as the message if the `Err` variant is held, and as such will fail your test.

Answer (score 1):

`assert!` can take multiple arguments, the second of which is a message

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert.html

e.g.

```
assert!(res.is_ok(), "Whatever you want to say or template");
```

Comment: Kind of a clunky way of doing it considering `expect()` is right there.